# Haskell Couldn't match expected type ‘Item Nat’ with actual type ‘()’

Tags: class, haskell

I am given this source code.

```
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat deriving Show
class FromList a where
  type Item a :: *
  fromList :: [Item a] -> a
```

and I should write the function `fromList` so it converts like this, for example:

```
fromList [(),(),()] :: Nat
===> Succ (Succ (Succ Zero))
```

My code is

```
instance FromList Nat where
  fromList [] = Zero
  fromList (a:as) = Succ (fromList as :: Nat)
```

If I use `fromList [] :: Nat` then the Answer is just `Zero` so it's right
but when I use `fromList [(),(),()] :: Nat`, I get an error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Item Nat’ with actual type ‘()’
    • In the expression: ()
      In the first argument of ‘fromList’, namely ‘[(), (), ()]’
      In the expression: fromList [(), (), ()] :: Nat
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You haven't defined `Item Nat` in your instance; add the line `type Item Nat = ()` and it will work.

Comment: Please do not use `->` to mean "evaluates to". If we read `expression :: T -> U` we read that as a function type.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works now :). Okay @chi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `Item t` for each instance of a type `t` that you implement. In other words, this can be solved with the addition of one line

```
instance FromList Nat where
  type Item Nat = ()
  fromList [] = Zero
  fromList (a:as) = Succ (fromList as :: Nat)
```

Now `Item Nat` and `()` are unifiable and no error will occur.